# Convert char from big endian to little endian in C

Tags: c, char, endianness

I'm trying to convert a char variable from big endian to little endian.

Here it is exactly:

```
char name[12];
```

I know how to convert an int between big and little endian, but the char is messing me up.

I know I have to convert it to integer form first, which I have.

For converting an int this is what I used:

```
(item.age >> 24) | ((item.age >> 8) & 0x0000ff00) | ((item.age << 8) & 0x00ff0000) | (item.age << 24);
```

For converting the char, I'd like to do it in the same way, if possible, just because this is the only way I understand how to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Endianess only affects byte order. Since `char` is exactly one byte it is the same on all endianess formats.

And as a note: you may want to look up the endianess conversion functions in libc:

```
htonl, htons
ntohl, ntohs
```

Comment: So I don't need to do a thing to it?

Comment: @PM No :) Don't worry about `char`.

Comment: @PM: Things would be different for wide characters, `wchar_t` though.

Comment: @SergeyL. Thank You! That makes things much more simple!

Comment: I have never seen a big endian system. All machines having intel processors are little-endian I think.

Comment: I have this little confusion. Reading the **bits** from highest address to the lowest on a big-endian system and reading the **bits** from the lowest to the highest address on a little-endian system should exactly be the same. But we are reversing the order of **bytes** and the **bit** order would be messed up. How is this handled?

Comment: @ajay ARM is big endian and that is in every mobile phone nowadays.

Comment: @SergeyL.: As far as I know, the ARM processor can run in both big endian and little endian mode. On the iPhone devices it runs in little endian mode.

Comment: Endianess affect bits too, but not in integer types.  Bit endianess is often seen in serial communication - what goes first: the MSBit or LSBit?

Comment: Also, even if you're on a LE machine, if you're doing IP networking, you need to convert to/from BE format which is network byte order.

Answer (score 4):

Byte-order (a.k.a. Endian-ness) has no meaning when it comes to single-byte types.

Although `char name[12]` consists of 12 bytes, the size of its type is a single byte.

So you need not do anything with it...

BTW, the size of `int` is not necessarily 4 bytes on all compilers, so you might want to use a more generic conversion method (for **any** type):

```
char* p = (char*)&item;
for (int i=0; i<sizeof(item)/2; i++)
{
    char temp = p[i];
    p[i] = p[sizeof(item)-1-i];
    p[sizeof(item)-1-i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: I know, but I already knew what size int I would be dealing with, thank you though.

Comment: As old engineer once _complimented_ "I'll have to take back half of the bad things I said about you."  ;)

Comment: @P M These posts and answers are meant for more than just you, but as a reference too for others.  Even thought `int` size may not be a concern in this post's instance, the variant `int` size may apply to others.

Comment: is `char` guaranteed to be 1 byte on all machines by the C Standards?

Comment: @ajay `char` is 1 byte per the C standard.  But a C byte is not guaranteed to be 8 bits.  A `char` and byte must be a _least_ 8 bits.  See `CHAR_BIT`.  Certainly most systems use an 8-bit byte.

Comment: POSIX requires that CHAR_BIT == 8.